# Generate PDF's with Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My objective is generate every month a PDF.
I am using Prawn Gem.

Likes this:

```
../Generatepdf/July2015.pdf
../Generatepdf/August2015.pdf
../Generatepdf/Setember2015.pdf
```

etc...

So my problem is how to define the urls? 
I got a controller "Generatepdf" with a view "index.html"
I only can access of my PDF via:

```
../generatepdf/index.pdf
```

Controller:

class GeneratepdfController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
            pdf = ConsumptionsPdf.new
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "lol2.pdf",
                                   type: "application/pdf",
                                   disposition: "inline"
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Class:

```
class ConsumptionsPdf < Prawn::Document
    def initialize
        super
        text "example" 
    end
end
```

Comment: Why dont you use show method defined in routes like /Generatepdf/:report_date.pdf and than use that to generate your reports

Comment: It would even be better if on the first of the month you generated the reports for last month and stored them on some type of cloud storage and used carrier wave to manage those files along with a corresponding model. That way you wouldn't have to regenerate them on every request. Then have the control method redirect to that hosted file.

Comment: **Zahid** can you explain how I can do this ?
Thank you